# PDF is not rendering properly in Rotativa

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, fullcalendar, rotativa

This is my page.

```
@model   JNCloud.Web.UI.Models.AppointmentModel
@{
    Layout = null;

}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>UB-04-081A</title>
    <link href="~/Content/agency_media.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/agency_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/Common/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.naviDropDown.1.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-mask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/telerik.all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/scriptbreaker-multiple-accordion-1.js"></script>



    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.poshytip.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.poshytip.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.poshytip.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/calendar/fullcalendar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/calendar/overlib.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/calendar/fullcalendar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/calendar/overlib.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/form.section.validator.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="scripts/jquery164min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
    <!--local fallback for JQuery-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/Common/js/qyb8ood.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try { Typekit.load(); } catch (e) { }</script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="scripts/jquery164min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var arr = new Array();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SelectedScheduleEvents('@Model.PrintAgencyUserID', '@Model.PrintFiltervisittypeID', '@Model.PrintPatientID', '@Model.PrinttypeSchedule', '@Model.PrintDate');
        });
        function SelectedScheduleEvents(agencyuserid, FiltervisittypeID, PatientID, typeSchedule, date) {
            console.log('manoj');
            $("#calendar").empty();
            $("#LocationId").attr('data-val-number', 'Patient Name does not Exists');
            var cdate = date.replace('-', ' ');
            var d = new Date(cdate);
            var m;
            var y;
            if (isNaN(d.valueOf())) {
                d = new Date();
                m = d.getMonth();
                y = d.getFullYear();
            }
            else {
                m = d.getMonth();
                y = d.getFullYear();
            }
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next,today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                year: y,
                month: m,
                agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}',
                editable: false,
                disableResizing: true,
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function (start, end, allDay, Id) {

                    var Selectedtdate = start;
                    //alert('start'+start);
                    var todate = new Date();
                    //alert('todate'+todate.getMonth()+3);
                    //if (Selectedtdate > todate && Selectedtdate.getDate() != todate.getDate()) {
                    //if (Selectedtdate > todate.getMonth()+3 ) {
                    //    alert('Please select less than 90 days later from todate.');
                    //    return;
                    //}
                    AddEvent(start);
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                },
                events: { url: '@Url.Action("SelectedScheduleEvents", "Schedule")' + '?AgencyUsersID=' + agencyuserid + '&FiltervisittypeID=' + 0 + '&PatientID=' + PatientID + '&typeSchedule=' + typeSchedule },

                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                    var eventTime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, "h:sstt");
                    var Id = calEvent.id;
                    var apptype = calEvent.appointmenttype;
                    var clinicianId = calEvent.clinicianId;
                    var startdate = calEvent.start;
                    var enddate = calEvent.end;
                    var comment = calEvent.comment;
                    var meetduration = calEvent.duration;
                    var backcolor = calEvent.backgroundColor;
                    var patientIds = calEvent.patientIds;
                    var locationid = calEvent.locationId;
                    var lname = calEvent.locationName;
                    var visittypeid = calEvent.VisitTypeID;
                    EditEvent(Id, calEvent.title, patientIds, clinicianId, startdate, enddate, eventTime, meetduration, comment, backcolor, apptype, locationid, lname, visittypeid);
                },
                eventMouseout: function (calEvent, domEvent) {

                    if (!$("#events-layer").hasClass('mouse_in')) {
                        $("#events-layer").remove();
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#divLoading").hide();
            $("#hdnCurrentDate").val(0);

        }
    </script>

</head>

<body style="padding: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="display: none">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SelectedPID)</div>
    <div class="widget first">
        <div>
            <div id="calendar" style="width: 100%;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    @* End Confirm Assessment form *@
</body>
</html>
```

And in controller when I use this

```
return View(objappointmentmodel);
```

then it's look like this

[image]

And when in controller I use this

```
        return new ViewAsPdf("PrintCalendar", objappointmentmodel)
        {
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
            PageOrientation = Orientation.Portrait,
            PageMargins = { Left = 0, Right = 0 }
        };
```

then it's look like this. This isn't loading properly.

[image]

What should I do?

I have researched also about this. But I can't find a proper solution.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

i got similiar problem-

the rotativa didnt manage to handle the font-family.

when i use ARIAL the PDF looks good.

try also to change path to js and css file to a full path.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Rototiva recently to make customer print outs on the fly and I've ran into issues regarding relative paths as opposed to fully qualified paths. My strategy was to create a partial view and view model for the parts of my page that required jquery and images (rendered using the @Html.Action() helper) and then make the pdf with two different action results in my controller:

```
public ActionResult CustPrintOut() {
    // doing stuff
    return View("CustPrintOut"); // return a view that renders your partials
}

public ActionResult printout() {
    return new ActionAsPdf("CustPrintOut") {
        FileName = "printout.pdf"
    };
}
```